# SQL Join Tables on Different Servers and Import Tables SSMS

Tags: sql, ssms

I am relatively new to SQL so bear with me.

I need to do two things:
1. Join tables on different non linked servers
2. Import tables from Excel into SSMS (which I then hope to join with tables from already established servers)

I cannot link servers, and I do not have permission to use openrowset.

I am essentially hoping to create an Access type environment on SSMS. I would just use Access, but it does not seem to handle the amount of data we are using well and it is not able to link to all of the servers I need due to maximum column amount. Thus, I am currently stuck uploading data between Access and SSMS.

What are my options?

Comment: You can bulk insert excel csv's into SSMS easily

Comment: You could install the [SQL Sever 2016 Developer Edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-tools) and load all of the data to your local PC.

Comment: Wait when you say SSMS do you mean SSIS?

Comment: Edit: It is SSMS, not SSIS.

Comment: I'm wondering if I can somehow use registered servers?

Comment: So you mean Sql Server Management Studio? That makes things much harder. I'll have a think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you're using SSMS. Thats SQL Server Management Studio which is the standard tool for SQL Server. It's really just a tool for doing stuff on SQL Servers and hence it doesn't give you any sort of independent 'environment' in which to work. e.g. you can't import an Excel file 'into SSMS'. You can use SSMS to import an excel file into a SQL Server however.

To do what you're trying to do, you need somewhere to hold the data all in one place. It sounds like you're not allowed to create new databases or tables on the existing Sql servers. And your data is too big for access. This is tricky.

You could create a third server somewhere, e.g. on your own machine, as jradich1234 mentioned in comments above. You could use Sql 2016 Dev Edition

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-tools

Please note that depending on your environment (I assume you work somewhere) the same people that dont want you creating databases on the company servers probably wont want you making databases on your own machine.

Then once you've got that, use the import wizard to import the other tables and excel files you need into a private database. Then do your joins.

Hope that helps. The constraints you are working with (can't use openrowset etc) make this very difficult to achieve in SQL. Essentially you should probably go back to whoever gave you this task and tell them you can't reasonably do it without linked servers or openrowset or the ability to make a new database somewhere.